# what is the purpose of running npm install on a 3rd party SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I want to install this SPFx https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-enhanced-list-formatting where inside the instruction it mentioned 2 run those 2 commands after cloning the code:

```
npm install
gulp serve
```

I know the purpose of the second command, but my question is what is the purpose of the `npm install` and it is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will install the depended packages listed in the package file of the SPFX. So yes, its probably needed!

Package file: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/main/samples/react-enhanced-list-formatting/package.json

Answer (score 2):

`npm install` downloads the packages and it's dependencies. These packages are required to for the web parts to work properly.

The packages & dependencies required are listed in `package.json` file in web part solution.

And Yes, running this command is **must** for web parts to work as expected.

**Official Documentation**: [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install)

**Additional references**:

1. [npm install | how it works](https://www.stackchief.com/tutorials/npm%20install%20%7C%20how%20it%20works)